# Calculate car battery life using OBD parameters

Tags: electrical, battery, obd-ii

I want to calculate the battery life of a car based upon OBD2 parameters like engine load, distance traveled, Control Module voltage etc.

Can anyone please guide me as to how to do this?

If possible, at least the time taken for discharging the battery

Comment: What class and series will this vehicle be entered into?  What's the make/model/year of the vehicle?

Answer (score 3):

You will not be able to achieve this using OBDII for several reasons:

- The battery is charging while the engine is running, so monitoring battery voltage in this state will give a false impression
- Battery health is assessed while it is not being charged and under load. Unless there is a heavy electrical load like headlights, the battery will not be under sufficient load to do this with the engine off

Comment: Don't forget that every vehicle would be different, too. Too my way of thinking there just about zero chance of an OBDII system being a able to do this, with or without the vehicle being running.

Comment: Slow update speeds are also going to kill any hopes of instantaneous measurements like trying to check the voltage while starting.

Comment: Good points @Zaid